# Does the probability of obtaining a sample for which a new element will be larger than the sample approaches 0 as the sample size increases?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Choose arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and arbitrary probability distribution $D$ over $[0, 1]$.

For a given natural number $m$, sample $S_m = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_m)$ as indepentent identically distributed random variables from $D$. Let $\overline{S_m} = max ({x_1, ... x_m})$.

Now consider the probability that a newly sampled random variable $x$ will be larger than $\overline{S_m}$, that is consider $P({S_m})$ = $P_{x \sim D}${x > $\overline{S_m}$}

We are interested in the probability $Q(m)$ of obtaining a sample $S_m$, for which $P(S_m) > \epsilon$, that is:

$Q(m)$ = $P_{S_m \sim D^m}${$P(S_m) > \epsilon$}.

**a) Is it true that** $Q(m)\rightarrow 0$ as $m$ tends to infinity, **regardless of the initial choice of $\epsilon$ and $D$**?

b) If a) is true, **can one state an explicit bound function (parameterised by $\epsilon$ but independent of $D$)** $F_\epsilon : N \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $Q(m) < F_\epsilon(m)$ and $F_\epsilon(m) \rightarrow 0$ for large m?

Comment: I believe $P(S_m)=\frac{1}{m+1}$.  Does this help?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Not true: $P(S_m)$ depends on $S_m$ (or at least on its maximum).

Comment: @herbsteinberg if you sample $m+1$ variables and ask for the probability that the last one is larger than the other $m$, then that probability is indeed $\frac{1}{(m+1)}$. But here you have fixed the first m variables in advance (e.g. imagine all first m variables are 0) and then ask for the probability that the next one is larger than all previous.

Comment: As long as the selections are independent and have identical distributions, it doesn't matter.  I don't understand what you see as a difference.  I don't see any difference between sampling m times and noting $S_m$ and not noting $S_m$ before next sample.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Take uniform distribution as an example. Suppose you sampled m times and all $x's$ are 0. The probability that the next element will be larger than all zeros is 1, not $\frac{1}{m+1}$

Comment: You've changed the question to $P(x\gt S_m|S_m)$ from $P(x\gt S_m)$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't say it in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the CDF for the distribution $D$, and $y = \inf \{v: F(v) \ge 1-\epsilon\}$.
Thus $F(y) \ge 1-\epsilon$ but $F(t) < 1-\epsilon$ for $t < y$.
If $\max(S_m) \ge y$, $P(S_m) = 1-F(y)\le \epsilon$ but if $\max(S_m) < y$, $P(S_m) > \epsilon$.  Thus $Q(m) = P(\max(S_m) < y) = F(y-)^m$ (i.e. $\lim_{v \to y-} F(y)^m$).  In particular $Q(m) \le (1-\epsilon)^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.